# NullReferenceException when assigning rpt to CrystalReportViewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, crystal-reports

I want to bind YearlyBookings.rpt to my CrystalReportViewer.
But the CrystalReportViewer is null, why?

GenerateReports.aspx:

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReport1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="True" Height="50px" ToolPanelView="None" ToolPanelWidth="200px" Width="350px" />
```

GenerateReport.aspx.cs:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string ShowCrystal(string Year)
    {
                GetYearlyBookingTableAdapter da = new GetYearlyBookingTableAdapter();
                CRDataSet ds = new CRDataSet();
                GetYearlyBookingDataTable dt = (GetYearlyBookingDataTable)ds.Tables["GetYearlyBooking"];
                da.Fill(dt, Year);  
                GenerateReports gr = new GenerateReports();
                gr.crset(ds);
    }

public void crset(CRDataSet ds)
{
    YearlyBookings rpt = new YearlyBookings();
    rpt.SetDataSource(ds);
    rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("YearlyBookings.rpt"));            
    CrystalReport1.ReportSource = rpt; // here CrystalReport1 is null, why?
    CrystalReport1.RefreshReport();
}
```

Comment: Well it is not enough code to play with it, but isn't  CrystalReport1 null ?
Try to use the Debugger window, or the View windows where you can just type in C# expressions when you stop at a debug point.

Comment: Updated with more codes. Yea, i've checked and it's CrystalReport1 null, is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: @Student What is the definition of rpt.Load?? Doesn't it override your rpt.SetDataSource?

Comment: NullReferenceException to where? be more specific.

Comment: Check for `rpt.SetDataSource(ds)` and `rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("YearlyBookings.rpt"))` lines, possibly `CRDataSet` is null or `Server.MapPath` argument provides report path which "doesn't exist" (i.e. being already exist but using wrong path to call it).